# How to transpose columns in Excel by unpivoting the header row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, unpivot

I have an excel file with about 100 columns, each one with multiple entries. The header of each column is the location for all the items in that section. I am trying to transpose this data into a two column excel, the first the item # and the second the location (header from the sheet).

Any ideas? I was doing copy paste but it is slow and prone to errors.

Here is a sample:

[image: Input]

And I would like it to look like:

[image: Output]

Thanks

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are trying to do with just a few columns?

Comment: Can you share sample data and sample expected results?

Comment: Updated with example

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Power Query unpivot approach is the simplest.

Select your data and click From Table under the Data tab:

[image: From Table]

Select all 3 columns and click Unpivot Columns under the Transform tab:

[image: Unpivot]

Reorder the and rename the columns if desired and then Close and Load.

[image]

Comment: Darn, I am on Mac and it does not look like PowerQuery is available for this OS!!!

Comment: @Danconia Wow! I didn't realize the Mac version was so many years behind.

Comment: I was able to do it borrowing a friend's computer and got it done. Thanks!